# I want to learn about why I can't get results

Tags: java, hibernate

I reviewed a code that someone wrote because I can't get the result. the code is incorrect but at least I expect `List<Language> langList = criteria.list()` to return results from DB. I get the result when I run the generated SQL query on the same DB or correct the code as follows.

I want to learn why do not get the result

**code of incorrect**

```java
public Language getLanguageByCode(String code) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Language.class);
    if (code.length() == 3)
      criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("threeCode", code.toUpperCase()));
    else if (code.length() == 2)
      criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("twoCode", code.toUpperCase()));
    else {
      throw new RuntimeException("code incorrect");
    }
    criteria = criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Language> langList = criteria.list();
    Language lang = null;
    if (langList.size() > 1) {
      LOG.error("Query result size is bigger than expected!");
      lang = (Language) criteria.list().get(0);
    } else if (langList.size() == 1) {
      criteria.setFirstResult(0);
      criteria.setMaxResults(1);
      lang = (Language) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
    return lang;
  }
```

**Generated Query by Hibernate:**

```
    select

        this_.id as id23_0_,

        this_.three_code as three2_23_0_,

        this_.title as title23_0_,

        this_.two_code as two4_23_0_ 

    from

        language this_ 

    where

        this_.two_code=?

2019-06-12 16:12:15 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - EN
```

**code of correct**

```java
public Language getLanguageByCode(String code) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Language.class);
    if (code.length() == 3)
      criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("threeCode", code.toUpperCase()));
    else if (code.length() == 2)
      criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("twoCode", code.toUpperCase()));
    else {
      throw new RuntimeException("code incorrect");
    }
    criteria = criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Language> langList = criteria.list();
    if (langList.size() == 0)
      return null;

    if (langList.size() > 1)
      LOG.error("Query result size is bigger than expected!");

    return langList.get(0);
  }
```

Comment: You definitly don't want to execute the query 2 times as you do with `criteria.list()` and `criteria.uniqueResult()`. That is just bad practice. To answer the actual question I would need to know how many results your `criteria.list()` returns

Comment: yes, That is just bad practice, but I wonder why I can not get results this command `criteria.list();`. The results count can be 1 or 2.

Comment: Have you debugged and checked if after `criteria.list()` any data is in `langList`?

Comment: langList is an empty array and why? I'm expecting that langList have 2 items

Comment: does `criteria.list()` itself return anything? In eclipse you can select that call and right click -> inspect to see if that call itself returns anything. So far I can only see a difference in code after that call

Comment: no, `criteria.list()` itself return anything, and yes, the code is the same until this call but it is not working I do not understand so I will be happy if there is a someone that knows this and he tells why to me :) 

I tried it and always saw the same result, I wondered why?